# Why doesn't the ENV file get sourced by bash or sh?

Tags: shell

I'm using Zsh. Here is the `ENV` file:

[image: the ENV file]

and my `.bash_profile`:

[image: my .bash_profile]

, each with one `echo` command for debug. When I start a new shell process `sh`,

[image]

it runs as child shell, and there's no debug output. If I change to `bash`,

[image]

I get the same result, still no debug output.

I investigated from [this](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv/wiki/unix-shell-initialization) and learned that if I want `.bash_profile` to be sourced the bash should be run in **login** mode.

Next, I change the shell started on login to `sh`

```
chsh -s /bin/sh
```

and open a new Terminal tab, still nothing echoed:

[image]

Surely, if I login with `bash`

```
chsh -s /bin/bash
```

, the `~/.bash_profile` would get sourced

[image]

and the `ENV` variable get set and exported as expected. However, Why doesn't the `ENV` file, namely `~/.bashenv`, get sourced by `bash` or `sh`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I learned something could explain my issue when reading:

> For Bash users, the ENV file is read only when Bash is invoked with the name sh, with the --posix command-line option, or after set –o posix is executed (all of which force POSIX standard compliance).

Since variable `ENV` has been exported to subshells, `sh` would try to source the `ENV` file, because this time I use the name `sh`:

[image]

So, here's the key point to fix this:

1. We should use the name `sh` to invoke `bash`.
2. `ENV` variable should be set and accessible first.

[image]